# Docker Server message error : You have reached your pull rate limit

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, amazon-eks, docker-registry

i try to install `k8s` after install some tools , kube throw me error

```
  Warning  Failed     10s (x3 over 70s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "kubesphere/ks-controller-manager:v3.3.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/kubesphere/ks-controller-manager:v3.3.1": failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/kubesphere/ks-controller-manager/manifests/sha256:47a8ae9cb4f6f044aaa554727c81bafd67b5c05b5d90fbc707ac67938e62c6d7: 429 Too Many Requests - Server message: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

after that i try to google this error ,i find solution to log in `dockerhub` account all machine, but i have still this problem.
does anyone know what is solution ?

Comment: Use a different docker-registry, not docker-hub.

Comment: But i install charts for example helm install nginx , it's defend helm charts where download this image from dockerhub or aswhub

Comment: There is usually (not always, but usually) a Helm chart setting to point at a registry mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated users in docker hub are limited to 200 container image pull requests in six hours.
So if you need more than this limit you need a pro account in docker hub.
You can mitigate this limitation by using a local repo as a pull-through cache as described here :
https://github.com/t83714/docker-registry-mirror